# Do non-convex platonic solids exist?

Tags: geometry, platonic-solids

Consider a solid with the following properties -

1. It is composed of congruent, regular polygons.
2. At each vertex, the same number of edges and faces meet.

This is the same as the requirement for the Platonic solids, but the solid need not be convex. Of course, the five Platonic solids will satisfy these conditions, but are there any others?

EDIT: consider the topological proof given in the Wikipedia article on Platonic solids - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid

If we require the Euler characteristic to be 1 instead of 2 (as in the proof) we get -

$$\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2E}$$

This still keeps open the possibility (using the same argument as for the Platonic solids given in that proof) of five such solids with Euler characteristic 1 (so they won't be convex). Question is, do these solids exist?

Comment: If you drop the regularity requirement, you get [Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%E2%80%93Poinsot_polyhedron).

Comment: @NoahSchweber - these are interesting, but I don't think they satisfy the requirement that each vertex should have the same number of faces and edges intersecting at it.

Comment: They do, actually… the faces or vertex arrangements are regular _star_ polyhedra.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel can you provide an example of such a polyhedron?

Comment: What @NoahSchweber said

Comment: When I look at the solids mentioned in the link he provided, none of them seem to satisfy my second requirement. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RohitPandey Whoops, I think you're right. I'll leave my comment up since they're an interesting class of polytopes.

Comment: The Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra do satisfy the requirements because the non-convex "vertices" are not considered vertices of the polyhedra, they merely happen to be points where three faces intersect. For example, the [great dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_dodecahedron) is considered to have only 12 vertices and 12 pentagonal faces. However, since the faces pass through each other, I suppose you cannot really call it a "solid". It does not have a clearly defined interior, it is merely an arrangement of 12 pentagons with nice regularity properties.

Comment: @Rahul - "not considered vertices of the polyhedra" - that seems like cheating to me. I'm sure there is a good reason they don't, but you know what I'll ask next - if we don't ignore any vertices, can such a solid be constructed?

Comment: If the polygons are not required to be planar(?!), you get some interesting possibilities. For example, one can interpret the vertices and edges of a regular dodecahedron as belonging to a polyhedron whose faces are six regular-but-non-planar *decagons*. (Midpts of the edges of each decagon lie along some great circle of the edge-insphere.) Two such faces share an edge, & three meet at any vertex. The nature of the "interior" of such a face is open to interpretation. (My personal research ---with a combinatorial focus on the figures' vertex-edge "skeleta"--- doesn't dwell on surface features.)

Comment: @Blue - what do you mean the polygons are not planar?

Comment: @RohitPandey: I mean polygons that do not lie in a plane. :)  In the reimagined dodecahedron I mentioned, the midpoints of a decagonal face lie in an equatorial plane, but the vertices of the decagon zig-zag over over and under that face. Yet, one can still consider such a decagon *regular*, in the sense that one can rotate or reflect it onto itself just as with a standard "flat" decagon.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hjRvZYkAgA&ab_channel=janMisali There are 48 regular polyhedra

Comment: Side note: how do you make links in comments? I tried HTML and what SE uses in the answers, and neither worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The central question here was if there exist solids that satisfy all requirements of the Platonic solids, but aren't convex. On thinking about this, at least one such solid exists (which proves they are possible). When constructing an Icosahedron, we take five triangles and form a bowl out of them. Then, we put an intermediate "ring" of triangles on top of this and finally, another bowl composed of five triangles is put on the very top. Now, imagine putting the top bowl upside down. This leads to a concave version of the Icosahedron. Note that the Euler characteristic of this non-convex Icosahedron is still 2. And based on the edit to my question, there is the possibility of a solid with the same vertices, edges and faces as an Icosahedron (or any other Platonic solid) but having Euler characteristic 1. I'm interested in how we might find these solids as well, but I'll save that for another question.

[image]

Comment: If you required only that the number of faces and edges meeting at each vertex be the same, than you could construct quite a few "Platonic" polyhedra satisfying these rules; at least, you could invert just one vertex of a regular icosahedron, or two or three vertices that are not opposite. But these solids don't seem very "regular," which is why usually one requires at least that the region around each vertex be *congruent*, beyond just having the same number of faces. Then even without the convexity requirement, you only get the five, but I think you need Euler's formula to prove it.

Comment: This polyhedron is not regular and so is not one of the Platonic solids. A regular polyhedron has all its vertices within the same symmetry orbit, i.e. they lie evenly distributed on its circumsphere.

Answer (score 1):

There are four regular non-convex or "star" polyhedra, known collectively as the [Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%E2%80%93Poinsot_polyhedron) after their discoverers. Cayley named them:

- Small stellated dodecahedron
- Great dodecahedron
- Great stellated dodecahedron
- Great icosahedron

But they are not "Platonic", as this description is reserved for the five convex regular solids, which were first listed by Plato.

Two of these polyhedra do not obey the usual Euler formula $V - E + F = 2$, which caused much consternation until the formula was generalized for toroids.

All four figures self-intersect. There are no regular polyhedra which are non-convex but do not self-intersect.

Answer (score 1):

What makes a polyhedron regular is not *just* that each vertex has the same number of edges meeting at it, but that the vertices are *congruent*, just like the faces. Your example, the icosahedron with a vertex popped in, fails because the five vertices around the popped vertex are not congruent to the other seven.

In technical terms, a regular polyhedron is ["transitive on all its flags"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polyhedron), where a flag is, in three dimensions, a face, edge and vertex, all adjacent, considered as a unit, and transitive means that you need only rotate or translate to get one flag into the place of another, and there will be no outward difference unless you labeled. A slightly more stringent condition than "congruent", which allows reflection. Equivalently, a regular polyhedron is separately face, edge and vertex transitive.

If you specify convex, there's only five regular polyhedra, the Platonic solids. If you specify bounded, there are nine, the Platonic and Kepler-Poinsot solids. If you specify planar, i.e. the faces are separately polygons in two dimensions, there's fifteen: the nine before, the three regular planar tilings and the three [Petrie-Coxeter tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_skew_apeirohedron). And it just gets [crazier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hjRvZYkAgA&ab_channel=janMisali) from there - and even that video's only scratched the surface!